# Why use jet engines instead of propellers when designing new airplanes?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, propeller, engine

I'm looking at the 100 people project and I am looking at clean airplanes. Why did we stop using a clean source of lift, the propeller?

Comment: Turbofans (B737/A320) are basically large propellers, so we continue with propellers optimized for M 0.8 speed, and also continue with traditional propellers for slower aircraft flying at lower altitude (e.g. [ATR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATR_72), or Q400). For propellers, the actual source of energy is often a [turboprop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_%26_Whitney_Canada_PW100), that is a (jet fuel) turbine, like other airliners. This is not cleaner in any way.

Comment: Unless you're talking about a rotary-wing craft (i.e. helicopter), I don't really think the propeller creates lift - it's the airflow around (and most specifically below) the wing that creates lift. Also, in what way do you think it is a "clean source" of lift where a jet engine is (by inference) a "dirty source" of lift?

Comment: How are propellers cleaner than jet engines?

Answer (score 7):

Look into [Propulsive efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propulsive_efficiency) (and maybe also [this one](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4404/app-b3.htm)).  Turboprops have a speed of peak efficiency, which is around mach 0.6 or so.  If you try to go faster, it gets significantly less efficient.  A high bypass turbofan, on the other hand, is most efficient at a higher speed, maybe mach 0.8 - 0.85.  So the simple answer is: we switched from props to jets because people wanted to fly faster but didn't want to burn a lot of extra fuel to do that.